# Why is the audio button getting cut off in HTML 5 audio tag

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I have created a website which has both a mobile and pc version. On the pc version there is no play button but on the mobile version their is. For some reason on the mobile version, the audio tag keeps getting cut off and looks unprofessional. I have looked over many sources but still can't find a viable answer. Thanks in advance for any help. Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

audio {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: -300px;
}

</head>
</style>

<body bgcolor="black">

<audio controls>
    <source src="boxsoundownmaking.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

</body>

</html>
```

All help is greatly appreciated![image]

Comment: Do you have any screenshots that show the audio controls being cut off?

Comment: Yes. It will be hard because it is online. If you have a mobile device search up  boxwiththesoundofitsownmaking.net

Comment: This will bring you to the problem

Comment: I am looking at it on my mobile and the controls aren't being cut off at all. It could well be a problem on devices with certain resolutions. Is there no way you can screenshot on your mobile device and provide a link to it in the original question?

Comment: I will. One minute

Comment: It is posted above. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS does not appear to be responsive cross devices. On your browser you can use the toggle device toolbar to determine the size of your phone'screen and style it according depending on the type of devices you wish the audio would display correctly.

use `@media screen`

Learn more...https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Thanks again for the help